# Trouble retrieving data with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm struggling to retrieve data from a table holding basic information. I've tried to use odbc_fetch functions but I couldn't get them to work. Could someone show me how to retrieve the data from a certain row

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$employeeNumber = $_SESSION["user"];

$connect=odbc_connect("CoveringSystem", "", "");
$getData="SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Details WHERE EmployeeNumber ='$employeeNumber'";

$result = odbc_exec($connect, $getData);

## //I've tried to add the odbc_fetch functions here\\ ##

echo $employeeNumber;
echo $firstName;
echo $lastName;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be careful! This is not safe: `WHERE EmployeeNumber ='$employeeNumber'`

Comment: How could I make it safer?

Comment: Use prepared statements. See [odbc_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php). Example: `$stmt    = odbc_prepare($connection, 'SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Details WHERE EmployeeNumber =?); odbc_execute($stmt, array($employeeNumber)); $row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt);`  PS: Better use mysqli or PDO if you use MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this with mysqli :

```
// First connect to database 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


// Than make your query
$getData=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Details WHERE EmployeeNumber ='$employeeNumber'");
//Count row returned 
if(mysqli_num_rows($getData)>0){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getData)){
 $firstName=$row['FirstName'];
$lastName=$row['LastName'];

//then you can do whatever you like with your data 
}

}else{

}
```